# How can I synchronize two threads, one for functions and one for directx, and run ImGui functions in one of them?

Tags: c++, multithreading, directx, hook, imgui

I am trying to extend the functionality of a program, adding an analytics menu made with ImGUI.

The program has two threads: the main thread where all the program logic is executed, and the drawing thread, where all the DirectX logic resides. Both threads are not synchronized and run at different frames.

I need to execute functions of the program, for that I need to do it inside the main thread, but at the same time I need to show the output of those functions in a DrawList of ImGUI.

I tried to do the following:

1. I hooked a function from the main thread to execute program functions.
2. I save the drawlist of my main ImGui window in a global variable, to access it later.

```
typedef struct
{
    std::mutex m_DrawingMutex;
} tDrawing;

class Drawing
{
public:
    static tDrawing& GetDrawing()
    {
        return *s_Instance;
    }

private:
    static tDrawing* s_Instance;
};

std::deque<std::function<void()>> DrawQueue;
ImDrawList* DrawList = nullptr;

HRESULT __stdcall dPresent(IDXGISwapChain* swapChat, UINT syncInterval, UINT flags)
{
    // ImGui::Begin...

    if (!DrawList) DrawList = ImGui::GetWindowDrawList();

    std::async(std::launch::async, [&]
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(Visuals::Drawing::GetDrawing().m_DrawingMutex);
        std::deque<std::function<void()>> tmp = DrawQueue;
        while (!tmp.empty())
        {
            tmp.front()();
            tmp.pop_front();
        }
    }).wait();

    // ImGui::End...
}

void HookedMainFn()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(Visuals::Drawing::GetDrawing().m_DrawingMutex);
    DrawQueue.clear();

    if (SomeMainThreadFn())
    {
        State.DrawQueue.push_back([&] { State.DrawList->AddText(ImVec2(90, 90), IM_COL32_WHITE, "Example"); });
    }
}
```

But there are two problems: I still can't execute ImGui::* functions (ImGui is not thread-safe) and there is too much flickering!

What could be a good alternative to run ImGui functions in another thread?
Thanks!

Comment: I never used DirectX, but usually it is the GUI thread that is the main thread, and other calculations are running in other threads, if needed.

Comment: There are two threads, the main thread, where the program logic resides, and the GUI/draw, where the program draws its graphical stuff. Naturally, I can't use the ImGui functions outside of the GUI thread (DirectX 11 Present hook). but I DO need to call the program functions in the main thread to avoid crashes, but I also need to draw the stuff returned by those functions, so I need some kind of thread-safe "queue".

Comment: imgui is designed to redraw the screen all the time, so it's not really built for multithreaded/cooperative operations. You draw using imgui code or with imgui-compatible code/widgets, not outside of it.